# Как расположить div по центру, не игнорируя другой div

Tags: html, css

Нужно расположить div блок по середине так, чтобы он учитывал другой div блок, который находится справа. Сейчас div_block3 расположен по середине контейнера div_container , не учитывая, что div_block2 стоит справа. Нужно сделать так, как показано на картинке: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Красный блок нужно расположить по середине между левым краем и правым блоком div_block2. Но при этом если убрать div_block2, красный блок должен расположиться по середине страницы.

Текущий html+css код

```html
<style>
    .div_container {
    width:1000px;
    border:5px solid #000;
    height:500px;
    }
    .div_block {
    width:200px;
    margin:0 auto;
    background:#000;
    }
    .div_block2 {
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    float:right;
    background:#000;
    }
    .div_block3 {
    background:#ff0000;
    width:200px;
    margin:0 auto;
    }
    </style>
    <div class="div_container">
        <div class="div_block">Блок1</div>
        Текст текс текст<br><br><br>Текст текс текст<br><br><br>Текст текс текст<br><br><br>
        <div class="div_block2">Блок2</div>
        Текст текс текст<br><br><br>Текст текс текст<br><br><br>Текст текс текст<br><br><br>
        <div class="div_block3">Блок3</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Не указывайте, пожалуйста, ссылки на скриншоты в вопросе. При необходимости, добавляйте саму картинку в вопрос т.к. ссылки могут устареть

Comment: А HTML, CSS и JS код можно кстати вставлять через редактор на самом stackoverflow, что бы удобно редактировать и запускать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может быть вот так. Вспомогательные дивы нужны. Размеры проставил свои.

```
<div class="container">
       <div class="spacer1">
            <div class="block"></div>
       </div>
       <div class="spacer2">
            <div class="block2"></div>
       </div>

       <div class="block3"></div>    
   </div>
```

css

```
.container {
        width: 1000px;
        height: 700px;
        border: solid 2px #999;
        margin: 20px auto;
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        box-sizing: border-box;

    }
    .spacer1 {
        width: 100%;
        height: 30%;
        grid-column-start: 1;
        grid-column-end: 3;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
    }

    .block {
       width: 300px;
       height: 200px;        
       margin: 0 auto;
       background: #000; 
    }
    .spacer2 {
       display: flex;
       flex: 1 1 auto;
       justify-content: center;
       align-items: center;     
    }
    .block2 {
      width: 200px;
      height: 200px;
      background: red;

    }
    .block3 {
        width: 250px;
        height: auto;
        background: #000;
    }
```